# Data binding doesn't work for UserControl used as a DataTemplter in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/september/charting-with-datatemplates) uses inline XAML as a `DataTemplate` for `ItemsControl`. I'm trying to use custom `UserControl` as a template and getting some cryptic errors.

**ModelPresenter**

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<ExpandoModel> {
  new ExpandoModel { ["Value"] = 1 },
  new ExpandoModel { ["Value"] = 2 }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{ Binding Source={ StaticResource ModelPresenter }, Path=Items }">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <presenters:MyControl Item="{ Binding Path=Value }" />  // Issue #1 - runtime error about binding
      <presenters:MyControl Item="5" />                       // Issue #2 - Item has type "ExpandoModel", but should be just "double"
     </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Columns="1" IsItemsHost="True" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**MyControl.xaml**

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
  <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Value }" />   // Somehow works because DataContext = ExpandoModel, but I expect DataContext to be 5
  <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Item }" />    // Doesn't work, returns entire ExpandoModel instead of 5
</Grid>
```

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public MyControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public static DependencyProperty ItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Item",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(MyControl));

  public static DependencyProperty ComplexItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ComplexItem",
    typeof(ExpandoModel),
    typeof(MyControl));

  public virtual double Item
  {
    get => (double) GetValue(ItemProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemProperty, value);
  }

  public virtual ExpandoModel ComplexItem
  {
    get => ConversionManager.Value<ExpandoModel>(GetValue(ComplexItemProperty));
    set => SetValue(ComplexItemProperty, value);
  }
}
```

**Issue #1**

When I try to pass some item from collection to my custom user control using data binding, I'm getting this error.

```
XamlParseException: 
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Item' property of type 'MyControl'. 
A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject
```

**Issue #2**

Tried to debug the issue #1 and instead of data binding I pass static numeric value. When I try to use this numeric value in user control, it thinks that I passed entire ExpandoModel from the collection, even though I expect just a numeric value.

**Question**

Why I can't use dynamic binding like `Item = "{ Binding Value }"` in `MainWindow.xaml` and why, when I use `Item = "5"`, this property is st to ExpandoModel item instead of `5`?

Comment: The `DataContext` of the root element in an `ItemTemplate` is the current object in the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl`, i.e. an `ExpandoModel` in this case. From what I can see, you should be able to bind to the `Item` property though. Are you sure that you don't have any other type named `MyControl `?

Comment: @mm8 that's the thing, static binding `Item=5` works, it just incorrectly returns data type of the argument. After binding, in MyControl it should be equal to 5, but instead I'm getting the whole model, not just its property. In other words, something was bound, but not what I expect. Both issues make me think that I made something wrong with DependencyProperties...

Comment: BTW you shouldn't add such dependency properties to a `UserControl` as you're currently doing. These properties look model-related or viewmodel-related, but not view-related.

Comment: What is ExpandoModel? Is this suppose to be similar to the ExpandoObject?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot it's like a mix of `dynamic` and `IDictionary` on steroids. An object that is a strict type itself, but can be extended with additional properties in runtime https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/feb/08/creating-a-dynamic-extensible-c-expando-object

Comment: @dymanoid I was going to use MVVM, but first wanted to make it work with the simplest case, using only XAML code-behind